# Retrieve Item from realm sort by id

Tags: kotlin, realm

I've a realm class A in my android project -

```
open class A(
    var id: Int? = null,
    var level: String? = null,
    var state: String? = null,
    var updated_at: String? = null,
    var created_at: String? = null,
    var person: Person? = null
): RealmObject()
```

and Person -

```
open class Person(
    var id: Int? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null,
    var url: String? = null
): RealmObject()
```

I can retrieve list of items of class A sorted by Class A's id attribute -

```
fun getItemsOfA() : List<A> {
    val listToBeReturn: MutableList<A> = mutableListOf()
    DBManager.getRealm().executeTransection { realm ->
        val tempList = realm.where(A::class.java).sort("id").findAll()
        for (item in tempList) {
            listToBeReturn.add(item)
        }
```

And I'm getting sorted list. But I want to have a sorted list by the Person's id attribute instead of A's id. Any insight on this.

How can I achieve these?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: SO is not a code writing service - we are here to help with existing code issues. Please update your question with what you've attempted and we'll take a look. Also, [Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/query-language/) are covered in the Getting Started Guide documentation so that'a a great place to learn how to sort and filter data. More info is available about [Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Something like `sort("person.id"`) will do it.